# BigQuery - substr() cannot be negative

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I went from hive to bigQuery.
But when I run the query, I got this message: `Third argument in SUBST() cannot be negative.`

```
Substr(variable, instr(variable, ‘a’)+2, instr(variable, ‘f’) - instr(variable, ‘a’) - 3)
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Can you give some sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Example : variable = 14526a utfsd f azd —> result : utfsd

Comment: What is the criteria to achieve the result? The word where the previous word ends with `a` and the next word starts with `f`? Are words always separated by spaces?

Comment: The basic error being reported is when the expression `instr(variable, ‘f’) - instr(variable, ‘a’) - 3` is negative it's invalid as the third argument to `SUBSTR(,,)`. So is the problem how to deal with cases that don't conform to your pattern (e.g. the first 'f' is fewer than than 3 characters after the first 'a')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the super powerful regex string function (extract and substring). Here an example

```
with input as (select "14526a utfsd f azd" as data)
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(data,"[a-z]{5}") from input
```